# Use Stream or DataContracts in a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, stream, datacontract

In my WCF services, I have been sending all data in the body of the post as a `Stream`. When the stream is received, it is read to a string and deserialized to the object it is "supposed" to be.

I've been looking at using `DataContracts` and trying to see any pros or cons they have versus using a `Stream`. The biggest thing I've seen so far, is that it takes a bit of a redundant step away - I no longer have to read the stream to a string and deserialize it to an object.

Are there any other noticeable differences to these two approaches?

For example my definition currently looks like...

`void LogOn(Stream input)`

it would switch to...

`void LogOn(LoginModel model)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that doing serialization/deserialization yourself will carry a performance penalty over the library methods. Also, your current approach does not expose any information about your parameters or return types, so you lose all the benefits of a strongly typed interface.